# $watch in parent's directive doesn't catch child directive changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directives :

```
directives.parentDirective = function(){
 return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller : function($scope){
        $scope.childs = {};
        this.registerChild = function(ctrl, type){
            $scope.childs[type] = ctrl;             
        };

        this.triggerChange = function(ctrl, type){                
            $scope.childs[type] = ctrl;
        };
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watchCollection('childs', function(value){
            console.debug("WATCH triggered for ");
            console.debug(value);
        });
    }
};
```

and

```
directives.childDirective = function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require : ['ngModel', '^parentDirective'],
    scope: {
       'model' : '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl[1].registerChild(ctrl[0],ctrl[0].$name); //Works nice

        scope.$watch('model', function(value){
            ctrl[1].triggerChange(ctrl[0], ctrl[0].$name);
            //the call to triggerChange works ok.
        });
    }
};
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div parentDirective="so rocks">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" childDirective="whatever"/>
</div>
```

And the controller is extremelly basic : with just

```
$scope.user={name:"batman";}
```

what happens is that the parentDirective $watchCollection doesn't  catch any changes.

It does catch the initial registerChild function.

I tried to put an scope.$apply(); but with no luck.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but it would help if you posted a working fiddle.

Comment: That `$watchCollection` call should work. As a sanity check, try invoking your `triggerChange` function with some different input arguments to see the watch trigger. It doesn't look like `ctrl[0]` and `ctrl[0].$name` will change from the code you've included here.

Comment: @miqid ctrl[0].$viewValue would change. I am not sure that $watchCollection is working recursively. I tweaked my code a bit more and realized that it was actuay working in the case I wasn't using object collections.

Comment: @Mosho I am trying to implement a directive that can manage multiple inputs (For a 3 select box datepicker for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the DOM you must refer to directives using the [dash-delimited](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) form, not camelCase normalized form:

```
<div parent-directive="so rocks">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" child-directive="whatever"/>
</div>
```

Here is a plunker, showing that the parent watch is working:
http://plnkr.co/wNUcsWuGQvCt779kB6ij

As miqid pointed out in the comments, the child watch wasn't changing the type.  I changed type to a number and increment it in each watch to force a change for the parent to see.

Comment: The '-' was a typo. My code isn't working because I suspect $watchCollection to not watch recursively.